# Insert padding so that points do not overlap with y or x-axis

Tags: d3.js

I have the created this plot in D3: http://bl.ocks.org/cddesja/aee65f660c24cb2144fd

There are two things I would like to change.

1) I would like to make it so that none of my points overlap with the y or x-axis. I thought I could use `transform()` to create a little bit of a buffer but that creates a gap between the x and y axis lines, something I do not want. How should I do this correctly?

2) I would like to get rid of the tick marks at the intersection of the x and y lines. I am hoping that once I move the tick marks (and subsequently the pts and lines) that these tick marks automagically disappear. I don't know if that's really true or not.

Thanks in advance.
Chris

Answer (score 22, accepted):

1.)  This is controlled by the [domain](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Quantitative-Scales#linear_domain) of your scales.  Since your domains are set to the extent of the data, the axis starts there.  Easy fix is to increase your domain to be +- N percent of the range. Also, I recommend remove the `.nice()` as you'll just end up fighting it for control the of the range.

```
// get extents and range
var xExtent = d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.grade; }),
  xRange = xExtent[1] - xExtent[0],
  yExtent = d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.bin; }),
  yRange = yExtent[1] - yExtent[0];

// set domain to be extent +- 5%
x.domain([xExtent[0] - (xRange * .05), xExtent[1] + (xRange * .05)]);
y.domain([yExtent[0] - (yRange * .05), yExtent[1] + (yRange * .05)]);
```

2.) This is controlled by the [outerTickSize](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Axes#outerTickSize) option.  Just set it to zero.

```
var yAxisLeft = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(y)
  .ticks(yTicks)
  .outerTickSize(0) //<-- set to zero
  .orient("left");
```

---

Full working code sample:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<head>
 <title>Proportion of Students Suspended <body></body> Grade</title>
 <style type="text/css">
body {
  font: 10px Helvetica;
}
.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>
 <script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript">
// Set up the margins
var margin = {top: 50, right: 50, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width = 1000 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom
    yTicks = 5

var x = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var xAxisBot = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .outerTickSize(0)
    .orient("bottom");

var xAxisTop = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .tickFormat('')
    .outerTickSize(0)
    .orient("top");

var yAxisLeft = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .ticks(yTicks)
    .outerTickSize(0)
    .orient("left");

var yAxisRight = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .ticks(yTicks)
    .tickFormat('')
    .outerTickSize(0)
    .orient("right");

var line = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.grade); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.bin); });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var data = [{"grade":1,"bin":0.0398,"number":14943,"total":3.2306},{"grade":2,"bin":0.0605,"number":14128,"total":3.3778},{"grade":3,"bin":0.0777,"number":13590,"total":3.4621},{"grade":4,"bin":0.103,"number":13147,"total":3.7474},{"grade":5,"bin":0.1207,"number":12936,"total":3.7055},{"grade":6,"bin":0.202,"number":12857,"total":5.2757},{"grade":7,"bin":0.2534,"number":12962,"total":5.7908},{"grade":8,"bin":0.2561,"number":13362,"total":5.7759},{"grade":9,"bin":0.1873,"number":16618,"total":5.8429},{"grade":10,"bin":0.168,"number":14996,"total":5.4448},{"grade":11,"bin":0.1178,"number":13119,"total":4.3997},{"grade":12,"bin":0.0605,"number":12061,"total":3.8986}];

  var xExtent = d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.grade; }),
      xRange = xExtent[1] - xExtent[0],
      yExtent = d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.bin; }),
      yRange = yExtent[1] - yExtent[0];

  x.domain([xExtent[0] - (xRange * .05), xExtent[1] + (xRange * .05)]);
  y.domain([yExtent[0] - (yRange * .05), yExtent[1] + (yRange * .05)]);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxisBot)
    .append("text")
      .attr("class", "label")
      .attr("x", width/2)
      .attr("y", 28)
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Grade");

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .call(xAxisTop);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxisLeft)
    .append("text")
      .attr("class", "label")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", -40)
      .attr("x", -(height / 5))
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Proportion of Students Suspended at Least Once");

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + width + ", 0)")
      .call(yAxisRight);

  svg.append("path")
      .datum(data)
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr("d", line)
      .style("fill", "none")
      .style("stroke", "#3B3A35")
      .style("stroke-width", "1.5px");



  svg.selectAll(".dot")
      .data(data)
      .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("class", "dot")
      .attr("r", function(d) { return 10; })
      .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.grade); })
      .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d.bin); })
      .attr("transform", "translate(0, 0)")
      .on("mouseover", function(d) {

          //Get this bar's x/y values, then augment for the tooltip
          var xPosition = parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr("cx")) + 0;
          var yPosition = parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr("cy")) + 0;

        d3.select(this)
            .transition()
            .duration(500)
            .style("fill-opacity", .35)
            .attr("r", 20)
         })
      .on("mouseout", function() {
          //Hide the tooltip
          d3.select(this)
            .transition()
            .duration(500)
            .style("fill-opacity", 1)
            .attr("r", function(d) { return 10; });
         })    
      .style("fill", "#3B3A35")
      .style("stroke", "#3B3A35")
      .style("stroke-width", "1.2px");
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks. This doesn't exactly what I wanted.

Comment: Upvoted! what happens to this when you have 1 point? wouldnt xExtent[1] - xExtent[0] become 0

Comment: look at my answer, it should also work when data has no extent at all, since i'm working on range rather than on domain values

Answer (score 0):

even though this is an old question, I got the same need but I preferred to modify the `range` extent of both axis instead of inserting fake values into domain:

```
var x = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([20, width-20]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 20]);
```

here the working snippet:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<head>
  <title>Proportion of Students Suspended

    <body></body> Grade</title>
  <style type="text/css">
  body {
      font: 10px Helvetica;
    }
    
    .axis path,
    .axis line {
      fill: none;
      stroke: #000;
      shape-rendering: crispEdges;
    }
  }
  </style>

</head>

<body>
  <script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    // Set up the margins
    var margin = {
        top: 50,
        right: 50,
        bottom: 30,
        left: 50
      },
      width = 1000 - margin.left - margin.right,
      height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom
    yTicks = 5

    var x = d3.scale.linear()
      .range([20, width - 20]);

    var y = d3.scale.linear()
      .range([height, 20]);

    var xAxisBot = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(x)
      .orient("bottom");

    var xAxisTop = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(x)
      .tickFormat('')
      .orient("top");

    var yAxisLeft = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(y)
      .ticks(yTicks)
      .orient("left");

    var yAxisRight = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(y)
      .ticks(yTicks)
      .tickFormat('')
      .orient("right");

    var line = d3.svg.line()
      .x(function(d) {
        return x(d.grade);
      })
      .y(function(d) {
        return y(d.bin);
      });

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
      .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
      .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    var data = [{
      "grade": 1,
      "bin": 0.0398,
      "number": 14943,
      "total": 3.2306
    }, {
      "grade": 2,
      "bin": 0.0605,
      "number": 14128,
      "total": 3.3778
    }, {
      "grade": 3,
      "bin": 0.0777,
      "number": 13590,
      "total": 3.4621
    }, {
      "grade": 4,
      "bin": 0.103,
      "number": 13147,
      "total": 3.7474
    }, {
      "grade": 5,
      "bin": 0.1207,
      "number": 12936,
      "total": 3.7055
    }, {
      "grade": 6,
      "bin": 0.202,
      "number": 12857,
      "total": 5.2757
    }, {
      "grade": 7,
      "bin": 0.2534,
      "number": 12962,
      "total": 5.7908
    }, {
      "grade": 8,
      "bin": 0.2561,
      "number": 13362,
      "total": 5.7759
    }, {
      "grade": 9,
      "bin": 0.1873,
      "number": 16618,
      "total": 5.8429
    }, {
      "grade": 10,
      "bin": 0.168,
      "number": 14996,
      "total": 5.4448
    }, {
      "grade": 11,
      "bin": 0.1178,
      "number": 13119,
      "total": 4.3997
    }, {
      "grade": 12,
      "bin": 0.0605,
      "number": 12061,
      "total": 3.8986
    }];

    x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {
      return d.grade;
    })).nice();
    y.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {
      return d.bin;
    })).nice();

    svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxisBot)
      .append("text")
      .attr("class", "label")
      .attr("x", width / 2)
      .attr("y", 28)
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Grade");

    svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .call(xAxisTop);

    svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxisLeft)
      .append("text")
      .attr("class", "label")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", -40)
      .attr("x", -(height / 5))
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Proportion of Students Suspended at Least Once");

    svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + width + ", 0)")
      .call(yAxisRight);

    svg.append("path")
      .datum(data)
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr("d", line)
      .style("fill", "none")
      .style("stroke", "#3B3A35")
      .style("stroke-width", "1.5px");



    svg.selectAll(".dot")
      .data(data)
      .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("class", "dot")
      .attr("r", function(d) {
        return 10;
      })
      .attr("cx", function(d) {
        return x(d.grade);
      })
      .attr("cy", function(d) {
        return y(d.bin);
      })
      .attr("transform", "translate(0, 0)")
      .on("mouseover", function(d) {

        //Get this bar's x/y values, then augment for the tooltip
        var xPosition = parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr("cx")) + 0;
        var yPosition = parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr("cy")) + 0;

        d3.select(this)
          .transition()
          .duration(500)
          .style("fill-opacity", .35)
          .attr("r", 20)
      })
      .on("mouseout", function() {
        //Hide the tooltip
        d3.select(this)
          .transition()
          .duration(500)
          .style("fill-opacity", 1)
          .attr("r", function(d) {
            return 10;
          });
      })
      .style("fill", "#3B3A35")
      .style("stroke", "#3B3A35")
      .style("stroke-width", "1.2px");
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```